# Handling TypeScript compiler for specific output

Tags: typescript

`TypeScript` is lot of huge. The most problem by me are the output of the compiled javascript code.

I had create over years my special code-style and i don't want to use the predefined extensions like `webpack`, `AMD`, `System` and other. In my head looks like "Hey, why webpack makes so ugly code and overload the script with thousand polyfills?".

I wan't to use TypeScript, but i want clean code. The code is not for humans and must not readable, but it's a special thinks in my brain, that says "dont use TypeScript, the code will be trashed".

Currently, when i design a Javascript "class", it looks like this:

```
const MyClass = function MyClass() {
    let _whatever = null;

    this.init = function init() {
        _whatever = 1234;
    };

    this.getWatEver = function getWhatEver() {
        return _whatever;
    };

    this.init.apply(this, arguments);
};

new MyClass();
```

Has TypeScript some methods, to define the output of the compiler?

Webpack for sample puts some irrelevant code to the compiled source like

> Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });

and other - I want code that has quality!

Comment: It's important to keep in mind that the fact you don't know what this output is for doesn't mean that it is 'trash'. Webpack does the job (so do other commonly used tools), and its job is to make the output efficient, not aesthetically pleasant (not sure which polyfills you're talking about but Webpack's footprint is low).

Comment: I am agree with Adrian, you don't go to the MSIL to see if it is pretty or to go to the assembly code to see if it is beautifully created. and it is the same I programmed in assembler and when I decided to code in Delphi, I did not complain about the assembler generated, because the importante things in the speed of development and the confiability of the generated code. try to maintain a style in JavaScript is the same to try to maintain a style in the generated assembly code. it is simple a step further in evolution.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler output is supposed to provide expected spec-compliant behaviour (with some trade-offs) when being evaluated while having reasonable footprint. It doesn't necessarily have to conform to developer's personal perception of *quality*, which is subjective.

There are numerous [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) that can provide extra output. All of them serve specific purposes, those options that aren't essential aren't enabled by default.

For instance, [`esModuleInterop` option improves module interoperability](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#support-for-import-d-from-cjs-form-commonjs-modules-with---esmoduleinterop) and results in extra output; it isn't enabled by default.

This line

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

is added with `module` option set to `commonjs` (default for ES5 target), [`__esModule` property](http://2ality.com/2017/01/babel-esm-spec-mode.html#es-module-imports-are-live-views-of-exports) is essential for interoperability with CommonJS modules.

It's possible to skip it with `module` option set to `es6` or `esnext` if the ES modules aren't handled by means of TypeScript (Webpack, native ES modules, etc).

It's possible to skip all module-related output with `module` option set to `none`. As the name suggests, this option means that modules can't be used at all.